# Failing to connect using MQTT Android Service

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm currently working on a small "Panic Button" app supposed to operate in a medical facility. As one of the project's assumptions is to be Internet-independent, I've decided to go for MQTT with a server set up in the local WLAN.

As I'm still an infant-developer, I've started off from a brilliant (yet already outdated a bit) guide by Dale Lane available at [his blog.](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) And just as him, I'm using [IBM's library.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24006006)

Beside rewriting the notification builders to fit modern Android standards, I've made no chages to his Service.

As the user should not have any control over the choice of the broker and topic subscribed, I'm basically hardcoidng it during the login procedure.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**SharedPreference is the most compact way to save variables on device's memory */
private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor sharedEdit;
private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("database",PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedEdit = sharedPref.edit();
    sharedEdit.putString("broker", "test.mosquitto.org");
    sharedEdit.putString("topic", "/hello/hello");
    sharedEdit.commit();

    Intent svc = new Intent(this, MQTTService.class);
    startService(svc);
}

...
...
...
```

This however does not work - not in AVD Emulator, nor on either of two smartphones I have available. Each and every time the notification I'm obtaining comes from the line

```
    notifyUser("Unable to subscribe", "MQTT", "Unable to subscribe");
```

Testing the same broker/topic with a desktop app I see it working normally, meaning the problem lays in my implementation of MQTT to Android.

At this point I'm not sure what steps should I take to create a fix. Perhaps I've missutilised Dale Lane's work? Perhaps the library he used is now outdated? Could anyone lend a helping hand? With the very basic skills of mine I'm afraid to mess it up on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale's work is VERY out of date, use the [Paho Android service](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) instead as this uses latest Paho Java MQTT client and is actively maintained unlike the old IBM code.

Comment: Ok. Will I need to 'translate' the methods from Dale's work so they work based on different library? Or are they both similar enough for the whole Service to get going without heavy rework?

Comment: No, it will take some rework to get it to fit, but it's choice between a library under active development with a vibrant community that can help vs a bit of code that hasn't been looked at over 5 years

Comment: I do trust you this is the better solution. Thing is - I've actually started digesting MQTT from Paho's sample app, but being split into dozen of different files and having interesting but - from my point of view - quite complex functionality... it causes me a lot of headache when I try to wrap my mind around it. That is why I ended up following Dale's not up to date, but - in my opinion - way more newbie-friendly guide. 

Still, seems like there won't be better solution waiting for me around the corner than to try to make sense of this code. Thank you very much for the answer.